# Call an F# function with its previous result until the output no longer changes

Tags: f#

Basically I have a function of the type `'a -> 'a` (an optimization function on a AST) and I want to call it (passing the previous result) until it returns the same thing as the input.

Right now I have this:

```
let performOptimizations ast = 
  Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> 0)
  |> Seq.scan (fun last _ -> optimizeAst last) ast
  |> Seq.pairwise
  |> Seq.find (fun (first, second) -> first = second)
  |> fst
```

This seems really convoluted because it is created an infinite sequence of `int`s just so that the scan will continue until the `ast` is no longer modified. I realized that I could also do something like this:

```
let performOptimizations ast = 
  let mutable newAst = optimizeAst ast
  let mutable lastAst = ast
  while newAst <> lastAst do
    lastAst <- newAst
    newAst <- optimizeAst newAst

  newAst
```

However, I would prefer to avoid mutation.

What's the functional, idiomatic way of doing this in F#?

Comment: Is this the sort of situation that could be solved in C# via the `yield` keyword?

Comment: @DanNeely I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DanNeely I don't think so. The final result here isn't a collection, it's a single item. The usual way to solve this in C# would be to use something like the `while` loop in the question.

Comment: The title of your post should be the function/purpose of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I general, I agree with what mavnn said in his answer, I just think the function can be written in a simpler way:

```
let rec performOptimizations ast =
    let optimized = optimizeAst ast
    if ast = optimized then
        ast
    else
        performOptimizations optimized
```

This method also sounds like a good candidate for making it more generic, something like:

```
let rec doWhileNotSame seed getNextValue =
    let nextValue = getNextValue seed
    if seed = nextValue then
        seed
    else
        doWhileNotSame nextValue getNextValue
```

Comment: I think you need a 'rec' in there. But yes, it's probably neater.

Comment: @mavnn You're right, I'm always forgetting `rec` in recursive functions.

Answer (score 3):

[F# supports tail call recursion.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203224524/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx)

Your algorithm would seem a perfect candidate for the approach, something along the lines of:

```
let performOp ast =
    let rec inner lastAst newAst =
        if lastAst = newAst then
            lastAst
        else
            inner newAst (optimizeAst newAst) 
    inner ast (optimizeAst ast)
```

By default tail call optimization is turned off in Debug compiles to ensure you get full stack traces in the case of an exception in the recursive function. If you are debugging with large asts you can override this option in the project properties.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is an old topic. Since I don't see my approach, I am still going to submit it.

I use a kind of a fixed point operator fix:

```
let rec fix f x = let y= f x in if x=y then x else fix f y
```

then the function

```
fix ast
```

will apply `ast` as many times to the argument as needed (or it will run forever if such an argument isn't hit). However, with this approach one has some flexibility with the "break-condition", maybe something along the lines.

```
let rec fix f condition x =
    if condition f x then x
    else fix f condition (f x)
```

where condition is of type `('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> bool`.